# Angular2 v4.0.2 and radio FormControls

Tags: radio-button, angular2-forms

I'm just curious if anyone else has had any issues with FormControl's and radio buttons. We recently updated to Angular2 v4 and radio controls which were working before have stopped. Given the below HTML and an associated FormGroup (not shown), the radio buttons can both be selected.  I really hope I'm just overlooking something simple but was curious if anyone else has experienced similar behavior.

```html
<input type="radio" formControlName="fcAdjustmentType" value="amount"/>                     <label>Amount</label>
<input type="radio" formControlName="fcAdjustmentType" value="percentage"/>                 <label>Percentage</label>
```

And before it's mentioned, the "name" attribute on the element is optional according to Angular:

> Blockquote When using radio buttons in a reactive form, radio buttons in the same group should have the same formControlName. You can also add a name attribute, but it's optional.

Comment: I guess you need to use name with that as well although its optional

Comment: Adding the name attribute does group the radio's properly, but regardless the FormControl doesn't seem to be functioning properly for  radios'.  Even though I can see the RadioControlValueAccessor's being created for the controls.

Comment: Lets wait for new build. may be they will update it